# Easiest way to display a range of lines in a huge text file? Don’t need to edit

Tags: bash

IN order to display from line 1 million, for 20 lines, I ended up with

```
head -1000020 myfile | tail - 20
```

That works and I’ve wrapped in a function that does arithmetic for it.  But I was wondering if there’s an existing bash or unix command for it.

Am on macOs, but happy knowing Linux for it too.

Comment: No, there's nothing built-in that does this. You can use `sed -n '1000001,1000020p' filename`

Comment: Agree w duplicate finding.  Cant delete though.

Comment: No worries, it's now a pointer for others finding this question first.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v n=1000000 'NR>n; NR==n+20{exit}' file
```

will exit early, useful if your file is very large.

Comment: this is a duplicate question but this answer doesn't exist on the linked one.